# How to use strings in RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*pg=p&kat=test&pod=1.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?pg=p&kat=$1&pod=$2
```

doesn`t work, why ?

I tested this one:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*
```

And it works, so apache is ok.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule needs to go on a new line.

Your rewrite condition says the query string should match

```
.pg=p&kat=test&pod=1.
```

and then your rewrite rule tries to match on

^something/something/

Surely that should be

```
^/(.)/(.)/$
```

?

so... what URL are you hitting?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, rewritecond, what i have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.* pg=p&kat=test&pod=1.* $ 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?pg=p&kat=$1&pod=$2
```

Space between (" * " and "pg") and (" * " and "$") doesn`t exists in .htaccess file

ofcourse RewriteRule is in new line

I`m hitting URL: www.test.pl/tested/1/